# Matplotlib: how to remove just one contour element from axis with other plotted elements?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to animate the estimation of the means and covariances of a mixture of gaussians (Gaussian Mixture Models) for which I need, at every iteration, to update the plots of the means and covariances.

This is pretty straightforward to redraw the means since I use lines which have a `set_data` method that I can call at every update. Unfortunately updating the covariances is another story since `contour` elements are represented as `QuadContourSet` objects and have no `set_data` method.

Here is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import mlab

# Toy data points (these are constant)
plt.plot(np.arange(-3,3,0.1), np.arange(-3,3,0.1))

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# First toy iteration
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 
                           1, 1, 
                           0, 0)

covariance1 = plt.contour(X, Y, Z1)

# Second toy iteration
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 
                       1, 1, 
                       0, 3)

covariance2 = plt.contour(X, Y, Z2)
```

[image: toy example]

As in the real problem I plot the means, the variances, and the data points, I do not want to clear the whole axis.

The question is how can I remove the first contour `covariance1` without removing the other elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for coll in covariance1.collections:
    coll.remove()
```

then update.

Comment: Embarassingly easy! I had tried with `for coll in plt.gca().collections:` Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with 3D contours (i.e. `contourf` from the `mplot3d` toolkit): `coll.remove()` gives:

`collection._remove_method = lambda h: self.collections.remove(h)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Any idea to remove such 3D contours properly? (It's possible to `coll.set_visible(False)` but the element remains)

Comment: Sorry, my bad - `remove()` **also works with 3D contours**. My problem was due to the fact that there were no contour lines created at some point in my animation (no horizontal contours for a horizontal plane!)

Comment: How do you get this to work if you use `contourf`? I can remove the contour lines but the shaded regions between the lines remain